# Android rxJava 2 how unsubscribe after complete task

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2

I have code which delete all user from my room database. For this I am using rxJava 2. The problem is that I subscribe to receive all users, delete all users after all, but I do not know how to unsubscribe from receiving information about users again.

```
fun deleteUser(user: User) {
    Completable.fromAction {
        appRepository.deleteUser(user);
        appRepository.deleteByUser(user.userName)
        objectiveActionManager.saveObjective(null)
        profileActionManager.saveProfile(null)
    }.subscribeOn(io()).subscribe()
}

fun deleteAllUsers() {
     getAllUsers().subscribeOn(io()).subscribe { users ->
        users.forEach { deleteUser(it) }
    }
}

fun getAllUsers(): Observable<List<User>> {
    return appRepository.getAllUsers()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

Comment: Dont subscribe in those methods, let the caller handle the subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a `Disposable` from subscribing:

```
 val disposable: Disposable = getAllUsers().subscribeOn(io()).subscribe { users ->
            users.forEach { deleteUser(it) }
        }
```

and when you don't want to receive any more updates or the lifecycle of your class ends you do:

```
disposable.dispose()
```

Comment: The point is that this support is not tied to the life cycle. I just need to get all users, delete them and call disposable.dispose (), but I don't know how to figure out at what point to call disposable.dispose ()

Comment: @Destroyer That's hard to day because your repository returns an Observable which potentially returns lists of users endlessly. If it returned a Single, you wouldn't even have to care, just get the users and delete them. 
If you can't change that, I'd just unsibscribe after the first emission of users, which is in the subscribe clause where you delete the users.